# css- hovering not working for svg element in li

Tags: css

i have  a list  li . it has svg icon and text . i given hover effects for li  to change text and svg fill color.but i had a problem

when i hover the li element , text changes its color, but the svg not changing . but when i place the mouse pointer (hover on svg element ) it changes the color.but the expected behaviour is whenever i over any place within the list it should changes color.

```
my code structure: html 

     <div>
     <li>
     <svg>
     <a>  </a>
     </div>


  css:

       li:hover{ color:red; fill:red;}

       svg:hover { color:red;fill:red;}
```

Comment: `color` applies to text **not SVG elements**. You may want `fill'.

Comment: i have added fill but it didnt work

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select the svg when the li is on hover. You should have something like this:

**HTML**

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <svg>...</svg>
    <a>Text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

Add path to svg selector

```css
li:hover svg path {
  fill: red;
}

li:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: See the edited answer, are you doing something like that? Otherwise, please add an example of your code in a codepen of something similar.

Comment: yes it worked for me i forgot add path in css.-    li:hover svg path  {
  fill: red;
}

Answer (score 0):

```css
li:hover svg, li:hover a{
color:red;
fill:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <li>
  <svg width="100" height="100">
   <rect width="100" height="100"/>
  </svg>
  <a>Link element</a>
 </li>
</div>
```